# CodeIgniter Active Records to compare two columns of same mysql table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'll get straight into the point.

My table looks something like this

```
CREATE TABLE user_orders(id INT(11), o_name VARCHAR(60), amount INT(10), discount INT (10), overall INT(10));
INSERT INTO user_orders(id,o_name,amount,discount,overall) VALUES (1,'first', 10,0,10);
INSERT INTO user_orders(id,o_name,amount,discount,overall) VALUES (2,'second', 20,20,40);
INSERT INTO user_orders(id,o_name,amount,discount,overall) VALUES (3,'third', 0,0,0);
INSERT INTO user_orders(id,o_name,amount,discount,overall) VALUES (4,'fourth', 40,40,80);
```

And this is what I'm tryna obtain:

```
SELECT * FROM user_orders
WHERE amount=discount
AND amount!=0 AND discount!=0;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5b09/3)

I am trying to fetch data from table when the fields `amount` and `discount` are same and are not equal to zero.

So using CI, I wrote this

```
    $this->db->select('count( id ) AS total_discounted',FALSE);
    $this->db->where('amount','discounts');     
    $this->db->where('discounts !=',0);
    $this->db->where('amount !=',0);

    $results=$this->db->get('user_orders');
    echo $this->db->last_query();
```

which produces query

```
SELECT * FROM user_orders
WHERE amount='discount'
AND amount!=0 AND discount!=0;
```

where amount gets compared to THE STRING '`discount`' and not the field `discount`.

How to achieve this kinda thing using CI? Any clues?

Comment: Try `$this->db->where('amount = discount');`

Comment: This worked. Please post it as an answer. @DishaV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `$this->db->where('amount = discount');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$where = "amount=discount";
$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'amount=discount' in 'where clause'

SELECT count( id ) AS total_discounted FROM (`user_orders`) WHERE `amount=discount`

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter 3:

```
$this->db->where('amount', 'discount', false);
```

the third parameter will [disable escaping](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#CI_DB_query_builder::where).